# Summing over a double infinite series to Modified Bessel function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, bessel-functions

Can we show that the series given below,

$$
\begin{align*}
2\pi e^{-1} \Biggl[ \delta(\xi) + e^{-|a\xi|} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+2j)!}{(n+j+1)!(n+j)!j!n!} \frac{|a|^{n+1} |\xi|^n}{2^{n+2j+1}} \Biggr]
\end{align*}
$$

be given terms of a single summation of Modified Bessel function of the following form

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(x)=2\pi e^{-1}\delta(x)+|a|e^{-1}\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{K_{n-1/2}(|ax|)|ax|^{n-1/2}}{2^{n-5/2}n!(n-1)!}\,?
\end{align*}
$$

This question is motivated by the answers given for a different problem that is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581824/fourier-transform-of-e-k2-a2k2/4582001?noredirect=1#comment9648993_4582001).

Comment: @metamorphy I have edited the question, are all the mistakes fixed now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this asks for an alternative expression for $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac z2\right)^{n-1/2}\frac{K_{n-1/2}(z)}{n!(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac z2\right)^{n+1/2}\frac{K_{n+1/2}(z)}{n!(n+1)!}$$ (at $z=|ax|$ with some irrelevant factors and terms). Just use $$K_{n+1/2}(z)=e^{-z}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+k)!}{k!(n-k)!}(2z)^{-k},$$ a known closed form; there are many proofs, say using induction on $n$ and the recurrences for $K_\nu(z)$, or the [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E8) $K_{n+1/2}(z)=\left(\frac z2\right)^{n+1/2}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{n!}\int_1^\infty(t^2-1)^n e^{-zt}\,dt$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\frac{2e^z}{\sqrt\pi}f(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z/2)^n}{n!(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n+k)!}{k!(n-k)!}(2z)^{-k}
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{2^{-n-k}z^{n-k}(n+k)!}{n!(n+1)!k!(n-k)!}
\\\color{gray}{[n=k+j]}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{2^{-2k-j}(2k+j)!\ z^j}{(k+j)!(k+j+1)!k!j!},
\end{align}
equivalent to the equality being asked for.