# Definite integral of a power of the sine or cosine

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Observing few results I have made one conclusion. Please tell me if it is correct or not. When limits of integration are $0$ to $n \pi$ and if function is $\sin^m x$ or $\cos^m x$, then answer is $0$ if $m$ is odd and if $m$ is even we can simplify it as $2n$  times the integration of given function with limits $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that I can use Walli's formula.

Comment: $\int_0^{3\pi} \sin^3 x = $?

Comment: ohh...according to my conclusion it should be 0 but after solving it i got 4/3...can you pls help where my conclusion went wrong ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the integration interval you're looking for may be
from $0$ to $2k\pi.$

If $m$ is odd then
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2k\pi} \sin^m t\,dt &= k \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^m t\,dt = 0, \\
\int_0^{2k\pi} \cos^m t\,dt &= k \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^m t\,dt = 0
\end{align}
as special cases of your earlier question,
[Definite integral of the product of powers of the sine and cosine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414211/definite-integral-of-the-product-of-powers-of-the-sine-and-cosine);
that is, we can apply the identity
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^m t \cos^n t\,dt = 0,
$$
either with $m$ odd and $n= 0$
or with $n$ odd and $m = 0.$

For even $m$ you are correct that you can use the
[Wallis Cosine Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallisCosineFormula.html)
for the interval $0$ to $\frac\pi2;$ 
the integral from $0$ to $2k\pi$ 
(or even the integral from $0$ to $\frac{k\pi}{2}$)
is just an integer number of "copies" of the integral 
from $0$ to $\frac\pi2.$